# Using a module's methods inside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, module, plivo

I'm trying to integrate an API into a class but can't work out how I put the modules in place.

```
class PlivoNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'plivo'
  include Plivo 

def initialize_plivo

 @p = RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
end

def delete_number
  self.initialize_plivo
  params = {
    'number' => self.number
  }
  response = @p.unrent_number(params)

end
```

I've tried both include and Extend

if I use in initialize

```
self.RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])

NoMethodError: undefined method `RestAPI' for #<PlivoNumber:0x007f8eca9523f0>
```

if I use

```
RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])

NameError: uninitialized constant PlivoNumber::RestAPI
```

Basically I want to be able to run @plivo_number.delete_number and have the app hit the api and perform the action. 
I appreciate that the initialize step not really doing anything with the class, but I can't do the next step without it.

Hope that makes some kind of sense, I get the impression that what I'm doing is probably a bit confused....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access `RestAPI` class after including `Plivo` module. Make sure you have installed plivo gem correctly. Here is more rubyish version of your code:

```
class PlivoNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Plivo 

  def delete_number
    api.unrent_number('number' => number)
  end

  private

  def api
    @api ||= RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
  end
end
```

Also you don't need to include Plivo module into PlivoNumber class, you could just use Plivo::RestAPI instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain Donatas' answer a bit further:

If you check plivo's source code (https://github.com/plivo/plivo-ruby/blob/master/lib/plivo.rb), you'll see a structure like:

```
module Plivo

   (...)
   class RestAPI
      (...)
   end
   (...)
end
```

In this scenario, if you `include Plivo`, you'll get all classes defined inside it (including RestAPI) as if defined locally. So, you can access them directly, as in Donatas' code snippet:

```
def api
  @api ||= RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
end
```

You could also, as he mentioned, just `require Plivo` in any Ruby class, and you'll have access to the RestAPI through its namespaced path. In a controller, for example:

```
require 'plivo'

class OperationsController < ApplicationController

  def plivo
    plivo = Plivo::RestAPI.new(ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_ID'], ENV['PLIVO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You can use gems defined in Gemfile without explicitly requiring them, Bundler does this automatically.

Comment: I'm trying this, but @p (or @api in your example) ends up returning nil, even though it seems to have authenticated correctly.

Comment: So when I run @p.get_numbers() (a plivo list method) I end up with an undefined method error

Comment: Ok. So long as I keep everything inside one method, then we're good. i.e. I initialize and carry out the api call inside the same method. Not sure what I was trying but I sort of expected @p to persist in the console so I could reuse it. I guess that's probably me being dumb.